# jQuery find nearest div input field and toggle

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to toggle user language and input field on click of the edit button(img). I have multiple fields like this so I would like one script that would cover all. My jquery toggles but also toggles the first div "Language" any help?

Jquery

```
$("img.optional_info_edit").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent(".field-row").find("input").toggle();
  $(this).parent().parent(".field-row").find("p").toggle();
});
```

And HTML

```
<div class="row field-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
           <p class="user-message-font">Language:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="p_info_form-hide_text col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
            <p class="user-info-font check_value_empty user-language">English</p>
            <input name="user_language" id="user-language-input" class="user-language-input form-control input-small" value="" style="display:none">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1">
            <img class="p_info_form optional_info_edit" src="assets/edit.svg">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).closest(".field-row").find.....`  BUT while you've two `p` elements it'll be better to use `$(this).parent().prev().find` .. OR if you want to hide all `p_info_form-hide` you can use `$(this).parent().prev().toggle()`

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Thanks great works! I didn't think to use .prev() :)

Comment: You're totally Welcome .. you can take a look at updated comment .. Have a great day :-)